# Datastax Studio License

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I was looking for the visualization client to be used in Mac for Cassandra DB when I found Datastax Studio which can be setup in local to see Cassandra db metadata and tables visually. I downloaded Datastax studio using below link:

https://academy.datastax.com/quick-downloads

I tried to look at the few links but couldn't understand about the licensing.

Can someone please confirm if it is free to use for non production environment within an organization?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataStax Studio License Terms can be found here https://www.datastax.com/terms/datastax-studio-license-terms.

I won't try to interpret or summarize, but I will highlight this portion:

> ...only in conjunction with the use of other DataStax commercial software on a trial basis, or for which you have an active, paid subscription.

Answer (score 1):

DataStax Studio will only work with DataStax DSE clusters; connections to OSS Cassandra are not supported. For more details beyond that, I'd recommend asking through DataStax Support.

Comment: I am not concerned about it working as I know it can serve my purpose. Just want to confirm if it is fine to use within organization for non prod environment.